# React component auto-remounted on state update, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent React.js component, passing a state and a setter to a child component.

Every time the child component use the setter, the child component is unmounted & remounted.
I'm new to react and I don't understand what is happening.

```js
const useState = React.useState;

class MyComponnent extends React.Component {
  intervalID = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING");
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      this.props.setA({ a: this.props.a.a + 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginTop: "30px"
          }}
        >
          {this.props.a.a}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

function App() {
  const [activeStep] = useState(0);
  const [a, setA] = useState({ a: 0 });

  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-multi-comp

  function StepPage() {
    if (0 === 0) {
      return <MyComponnent a={a} setA={setA} />;
    } else {
      return <MyComponnent />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <StepPage />
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Because you are constructing a new Component each time your state changes

Comment: Why aren't you simply returing `return <MyComponnent a={a} setA={setA} />;`

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI this is a minimal example reproducing my problem, in my real case I use StepPage() to do conditional rendering

Comment: I was writing you a solution, but I think felixmosh already did it.

Comment: I moved your off-site codesandbox link to a on-site stack snippet. Remember that you must include a [mcve] inside the question description itself and any off-site link only serves as additional references and shouldn't be needed to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your are creating a **new instance** of your component by defining `StepPage` inside a render function.

You can refactor your `StepPage` component so it will be defined outside of render method,

```
function StepPage({ setA, a}) {
  if (0 === 0) {
    return <MyComponnent a={a} setA={setA} />;
  } else {
    return <MyComponnent />;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [activeStep] = useState(0);
  const [a, setA] = useState({ a: 0 });

  return (
    <div>
      <StepPage a={a} setA={setA} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`StepPage` in your example is re-defined every time `App` renders.

Calling the function normally instead of using it as a React component alleviates the issue:

```
return (
  <div>
    {StepPage()}
  </div>
);
```

```js
const useState = React.useState;

class MyComponnent extends React.Component {
  intervalID = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING");
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      this.props.setA({ a: this.props.a.a + 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            marginTop: "30px"
          }}
        >
          {this.props.a.a}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

function App() {
  const [activeStep] = useState(0);
  const [a, setA] = useState({ a: 0 });

  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-multi-comp

  function StepPage() {
    if (0 === 0) {
      return <MyComponnent a={a} setA={setA} />;
    } else {
      return <MyComponnent />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {StepPage()}
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: By calling function component directly, in reconcialiation phase, react will assume that this part of tree has changed! and using jsx, react will know better handling your component! [Learn more](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/) in inversion of control section!

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear (and true)